# In SystemVerilog, will assign a variable to itself within an always_comb block generate a latch?

Tags: digital-logic, fpga, latch, system-verilog

In SystemVerilog, `always_comb` blocks must always specify the value of all the signals within them for all possible `case` branches to avoid latches.

However, are these latches generated if one of those variables is assigned to its current value?

In other words, having something like:

```
always_comb begin
   case (cs)
   2'b00: {a, b} = {some_signal, 0};
   2'b01: {a, b} = (a, 1};
   2'b10: {a, b} = {0, 0};
   endcase
end
```

Will the above generate a latch because the state `01` assigns `a` to its previous value?

Comment: Yes. Why else would you do this?

Comment: Sorry, I have edited the question to clarify. What I want precisely is to avoid latches, because I'm aware they are discouraged.

Comment: Please edit the question to explain what you trying to achieve (XY Problem?). The line you mention results in a latch for `a` and the lack of an output for `cs=11` results in latches for both `a` and `b`. The block *explicitly* defines these latches, so it becomes a matter to understand what is actually supposed to be implemented: if the module is supposed to implement storage, it probably should be implemented with FFs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 2'b01: {a, b} = (a, 1};

This will result in combinatorial loop on `a` because you are feeding back the output of the combi logic (say \$a =f(\text{cs}, \text{some_signal})\$) back to its input without any register in between (Making the combi logic function \$a=f(\text{cs}, \text{some_signal}, a)\$. A path like this cannot be verified for timing by a Timing Analyzer, and its behavior is undefined.

> Will the above generate a latch because the state 01 assigns a to its previous value?

You have not defined what should the combi logic do if `cs` = `11` inside the `case` statement. So Synthesiser will add latches on `a` and `b` to hold their previous values in case `cs` = `11`. This is assumed to be the intent of the designer by Synthesiser.

Something like this is synthesised on `a` for example:

[image]

The construct `always_comb` in SV, unlike `always @(*)` in Verilog, is strictly used to model combinatorial logic. So if the RTL within it is inferring latch, it should be notified at the compile stage and flagged as error.